Equation Padding/Spacing in Table
Having trouble fixing the bottom spacing with these display style equations in the table. What's the best way to fix this without manually entering spaces myself?

\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
                    \hline 
                \textbf{Name of Cross Section} & $A(x)$     
                    \\ \hline
                \textbf{Square} with side length $f(x)$ & $\left[f(x)\right]^2$ 
                    \\ \hline
                \textbf{Square} with diagonal $f(x)$ & $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\left[f(x)\right]^2$ 
                    \\ \hline
                \textbf{Rectangle} with base $f(x)$ and height $h$ & $h\cdot f(x)$ 
                    \\ \hline
                \textbf{Semicircle} with radius $f(x)$ & $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\pi\left[f(x)\right]^2$ 
                    \\ \hline
                \textbf{Semicircle} with diameter $f(x)$ & $\displaystyle \frac{1}{8}\pi\left[f(x)\right]^2$ 
                    \\ \hline
                \textbf{Triangle} with base $f(x)$ and height $h$ & $\displaystyle \frac{h}{2}f(x)$ 
                    \\ \hline
                \textbf{Equilateral triangle} with base $f(x)$ & $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\left[f(x)\right]^2$ \\ 
                    \hline
                \textbf{Right Isosceles Triangle} with legs $f(x)$ & $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\left[f(x)\right]^2$ 
                    \\ \hline
                \textbf{Right isosceles triangle} with hypotenuse $f(x)$ & $\displaystyle \frac{1}{4}\left[f(x)\right]^2$ 
                    \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
            
\end{document}


See Column and row padding in tables (possible duplicate). The cellspace package provides some functionality that could be of benefit.

I would probably just increase arraystretch, and not use the \hline

I'd get rid of the vertical rule and of most horizontal rules. And I'd replace all instances of \left[f(x)\right] with [f(x)] as \left and \right do nothing useful here.

\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs,amsmath,array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$\displaystyle}l<{$}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l L @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Name of cross section} & A(x) \\ 
\midrule
\textbf{Square} with side length $f(x)$            & [f(x)]^2 \\
\textbf{Square} with diagonal $f(x)$               & \tfrac{1}{2}[f(x)]^2 \\
\textbf{Rectangle} with base $f(x)$ and height $h$ & h\cdot f(x) \\
\textbf{Semicircle} with radius $f(x)$             & \tfrac{1}{2}\pi[f(x)]^2 \\
\textbf{Semicircle} with diameter $f(x)$           & \tfrac{1}{8}\pi[f(x)]^2 \\
\textbf{Triangle} with base $f(x)$ and height $h$  & \tfrac{1}{2}h\cdot f(x) \\
\textbf{Equilateral triangle} with base $f(x)$     & \tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4}[f(x)]^2 \\ 
\textbf{Right isosceles triangle} with legs $f(x)$ & \tfrac{1}{2}[f(x)]^2 \\
\textbf{Right isosceles triangle} with hypotenuse $f(x)$ & \tfrac{1}{4}[f(x)]^2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
 
\end{document}


Addendum: I can't help but point out that the table's appearance is marred by the appearance of the multitude of visually oppressive f(x) and [f(x)]^2 terms. Why not just write q and q^2, say? Then, when it becomes necessary to add some generality (elsewhere in the text, but not in the table), you can always start writing about q=q(x)=..., no?

\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l >{$}l<{$} @{}}
\toprule
Name of cross section & \mbox{Area} \\ 
\hline
Square with side length $q$            & q^2 \\
Square with diagonal $q$               & \frac{1}{2}q^2 \\
Rectangle with base $q$ and height $h$ & h\cdot q \\
Semicircle with radius $q$             & \frac{1}{2}\pi q^2 \\
Semicircle with diameter $q$           & \frac{1}{8}\pi q^2 \\
Triangle with base $q$ and height $h$  & \frac{1}{2}h\cdot q \\
Equilateral triangle with base $q$     & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}q^2 \\ 
Right isosceles triangle with legs $q$ & \frac{1}{2}q^2 \\
Right isosceles triangle with hypotenuse $q$ & \frac{1}{4}q^2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
 
\end{document}


Here is a solution with {NiceTabular} of nicematrix and its key cell-space-limits. However, I recommend a design in the spirit of booktabs (see Mico's answer).
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|>{\bfseries}l|c|}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=2pt]
Name of Cross Section & $A(x)$ \\
Square with side length $f(x)$ & $\left[f(x)\right]^2$ \\
Square with diagonal $f(x)$ & $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\left[f(x)\right]^2$ \\
Rectangle with base $f(x)$ and height $h$ & $h\cdot f(x)$ \\
Semicircle with radius $f(x)$ & $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\pi\left[f(x)\right]^2$ \\
Semicircle with diameter $f(x)$ & $\displaystyle \frac{1}{8}\pi\left[f(x)\right]^2$ \\
Triangle with base $f(x)$ and height $h$ & $\displaystyle \frac{h}{2}f(x)$ \\
Equilateral triangle with base $f(x)$ & $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\left[f(x)\right]^2$ \\ 
Right Isosceles Triangle with legs $f(x)$ & $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\left[f(x)\right]^2$ \\
Right isosceles triangle with hypotenuse $f(x)$ & $\displaystyle \frac{1}{4}\left[f(x)\right]^2$ \\
\end{NiceTabular}
            
\end{document}


